# Is the format of URLs imported to IP4.1 from IP3.9 correct?

Tags: url, plugins, import, export, impresspages

I have now successfully imported the text, pictures and pages from IP3.9 to IP4.1.

IP4.1 on localhost has truncated URLs.

> For example URL in IP3.9
>
> > localhost/ip39/en/top/graphene/cvd-graphen/cvd-on-metals/multilayer-graphene-on-nickel-foil/
>
> when imported to IP4.1 becomes
>
> > localhost/ip41/multilayer-graphene-on-nickel-foil

Is this normal ?  If IP4 changes the format of the URLs then I think all the Google links will be lost.
Alan

Answer (score 0):

Since v4.x we removed requirement to have language, zone or parent page in the path of pages. Which means that each page (despite its location in the menu tree) can have any URL starting from the root. You can put URL with slashes, too.

You have two options:

1. Manually change back all paths to the format you need (you can do that in the archive before import, too).
2. Create required redirects for search engines to understand what happened.

Comment: Many thanks, I am still trying to understand the philosophy of upgrading from 3.XX to 4.XX (4.xx has many things that would improve my website)...... Problem is I have about 1000 pages